# How to convert a date format like 'Wed Mar 13 10:10 EDT 2013' to "2013-03-13 10:10" in robot frame work or python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Could any one help me out to covert a date format like 
"Wed Mar 13 10:10 EDT 2013" into the format like "2013-03-13 10:10" , I have tried "get time" keyword from Built-in which isn't working in this case since RF is not able to recognize the date format like "Wed Mar 13 10:10 EDT 2013" . So is there any possible solution for this issue in python . Please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as dateparser
dateparser("Wed Mar 13 10:10 EDT 2013").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

> Out[6]: '2013-03-13 10:10'

Comment: I would have recommended using `dateutil` myself. Only point to remember is that it's an external library.